# Example of using torus knots in experimental science

Tags: general-topology, physics, knot-theory

Can anyone give an example of using the theory of torus knot in experimental science? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The paper, [Use of the Projected Torus Knot Lattice for a Compact Storage Ring FEL](http://accelconf.web.cern.ch/accelconf/FEL2012/papers/tuoc03.pdf), by S. Sasaki, A. Miyamoto such an example. In this paper the authors used the concepts of bundles and crossing numbers of several torus knots to determine how to design a free electron laser with required attenuation.